# How to add a watermark to Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Now that there is an official way to insert a watermark in google docs through the user interface, I am trying to find how to do the same from apps script.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Not all the user interface features are supported by Google Apps Script. Have you already reviewed the release notes / reference docs (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.